# Convert large XML file to CSV in PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv

I have a 50MB XML file.  I want to convert it to a CSV file, but most methods I have found exhaust the server memory.  Is there a good way to do this using a stream method such as XMLreader.

Comment: The answer is yes.

(feel free to post more details for a more detailed answer)

Comment: There aren't too many other details - I have an XML file, I want to put in CSV format, I have a bunch of alogrithms to do this but they all use too much memory.  Do you have an alogrithm that won't exhaust the memory?

Comment: Wait, Excel? You said XML in your original post. If it's Excel, do a File > Save As... > CSV to get a CSV output.

Comment: If this is just a single file and one time operation, why not google *xml2csv* or *xml to csv convertor* and use one of the freely available ones. No need to do this in PHP.

Comment: I want to do it in PHP because there are multiple ways that you could configure the CSV output.  I'd like to keep it in PHP so that I can control the output.  This is going to be part of an automated process so it is nice to have the method in PHP and not some windows GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use [`XmlReader`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) to parse the XML, as it works as an event based parser - Eg. it doesn't load everything into memory, but rather reads as it advances through the input file.

Answer (score 4):

the SAX-style expat-based parser is the most space-efficient option:

http://php.net/xml_parse

it will execute your $start_element_handler and $end_element_handler callbacks whenever an element tag is opened or closed, rather than keeping the entire document in memory.

but still, 50 MB is not a lot, maybe your provider can up the limit.

```
php_value memory_limit 100M
```

in .htaccess/httpd.conf, or set it in php.ini.

Comment: The file is 50MB, but the process uses much much more than 50MB.  I increased the memory limit quite a bit, but it still doesn't work

Comment: try xml_parse with those callbacks.. it will use very little RAM

Answer (score 2):

I've written this algorithm some time ago.. Feel free to give it a shot.

https://web.archive.org/web/20120423125804/http://sites.google.com/site/soichih/q-a/xml-to-csv-converter

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party...

for an xml structure of `<domains><domain><name>myname.com</name></domain></domains>`

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/my.xml";
  $returnData = file_get_contents($url);
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

     $csv = 'my.csv';
     $path = '/var/www/html/';

  $domain = $xml->domains->domain;

      $fullpath = $path.$csv;
      $fp = fopen($fullpath, 'w');

    foreach ($xml->domains->domain as $domain) {

        fputcsv($fp, get_object_vars($domain),',','"');

    }

    fclose($fp);

       header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
           header('Content-Type: application/csv');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($csv));
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
       header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
       header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
       header('Pragma: public');
       header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullpath));
       readfile($fullpath);

    exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase memory limit ? `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')`

(That's a very bad solution btw)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PHP API, but seems this class can help you: [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

Basically you're looking for a parser based on events, like old SAX. This parser type will fire an event, or something similar. It'll be memory efficient, as it doesn't need to load your entire document into memory.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML file is rather simple and could avoid going through a full-fledged XML parser, and could instead be read line-by-line by PHP and export each line as it goes, that would save having the whole file in memory at once. What's the XML structure?