# Convert XML to CSV with PHP

Tags: php, xml, converters

I'm using the following code to convert my XML file to a CSV format. Unfortunately, it seems to not be recognizing each entry in the XML and so the XML file ends up being blank.

```
<?php
$filexml='test.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
  echo 'File Exists';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
  $f = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
  foreach ($xml->Item as $item) {
        fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($item),',','"');
  }
  fclose($f);
}
?>
```

An example of my XML file is below...

```
<Item MaintenanceType="C">
  <HazardousMaterialCode>N</HazardousMaterialCode>
  <ItemLevelGTIN GTINQualifier="UP">090127000380</ItemLevelGTIN>
  <PartNumber>0-1848-1</PartNumber>
  <BrandAAIAID>BBVL</BrandAAIAID>
  <BrandLabel>Holley</BrandLabel>
  <PartTerminologyID>5904</PartTerminologyID>
  <Descriptions>
    <Description MaintenanceType="C" DescriptionCode="DES" LanguageCode="EN">Street Carburetor</Description>
    <Description MaintenanceType="C" DescriptionCode="SHO" LanguageCode="EN">Crb</Description>
  </Descriptions>
  <Prices>
    <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="JBR">
      <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
      <Price UOM="PE">462.4600</Price>
    </Pricing>
    <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="RET">
      <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
      <Price UOM="PE">380.5500</Price>
    </Pricing>
    <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="WD1">
      <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
      <Price UOM="PE">314.4700</Price>
    </Pricing>
  </Prices>
  <ExtendedInformation>
    <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="CTO" LanguageCode="EN">US</ExtendedProductInformation>
    <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="NPC" LanguageCode="EN">A</ExtendedProductInformation>
    <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="HTS" LanguageCode="EN">8409914000</ExtendedProductInformation>
    <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="NAF" LanguageCode="EN">B</ExtendedProductInformation>
  </ExtendedInformation>
  <ProductAttributes>
    <ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="SKU" LanguageCode="EN">BBVL0-1848-1</ProductAttribute>
    <ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="ModDate" LanguageCode="EN">2012-12-31</ProductAttribute>
  </ProductAttributes>
  <Packages>
    <Package MaintenanceType="C">
      <PackageLevelGTIN>00090127000380</PackageLevelGTIN>
      <PackageUOM>EA</PackageUOM>
      <QuantityofEaches>1</QuantityofEaches>
      <Dimensions UOM="IN">
        <Height>7.5000</Height>
        <Width>11.0000</Width>
        <Length>12.2500</Length>
      </Dimensions>
      <Weights UOM="PG">
        <Weight>13.500</Weight>
        <DimensionalWeight>6.09</DimensionalWeight>
      </Weights>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Item>
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: is the file writable ?

Comment: Yes. I used a simpler example and it worked. :)

Comment: Did you get any error? or improper csv file?

Comment: The file just didn't populate at all. I didn't get any errors.

Comment: Your answer in here :)
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129001/convert-large-xml-file-to-csv-in-php

Comment: @hadirasouli perhaps not, as his XML is not that huge. But the link you quoted have reference links to other parser options.

Comment: I'm not a php expert but It might be possible that you are not parsing it right because you have an attribute in your root and child tags like in `<Item MaintenanceType="C">` there is `MaintenanceType="C"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
function createCsv($xml, $f)
{
    foreach ($xml->children() as $item) {
        $hasChild = (count($item->children()) > 0) ? true : false;
        if (!$hasChild) {
            $put_arr = array($item->getName(), $item);
            fputcsv($f, $put_arr, ',', '"');
        } else {
            createCsv($item, $f);
        }
    }
}

$filexml = 'test.xml';

if (file_exists($filexml)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
    $f = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
    createCsv($xml, $f);
    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: It is possible to do this, but with columns for each node? I would like to get a xml and use the nodes types as column headers.

Comment: Using this for music XML, a lot of important info is left out of the CSV.