# XML to CSV with PHP - Fix Format

Tags: php, xml, csv, converters

I'm currently using the following code to convert my XML file to a CSV file...

```
<?php
$filexml='test.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
    $f = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
    print_r($xml);
    createCsv($xml, $f);
    fclose($f);
}
function createCsv($xml,$f)
    {

        foreach ($xml->children() as $item) {

            $hasChild = (count($item->children()) > 0)?true:false;

            if( ! $hasChild) {
                $put_arr = array($item);
                fputcsv($f, $put_arr ,',','"');
            }
            else
            {
                createCsv($item, $f);
            }

        }

    }
?>
```

I'm only having two issues right now. First of which, I'm trying to include only the data for  as opposed to  and the other fields. The sample of my XML data is below...

```
<PIES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="www.aftermarket.org/eCommerce/Pies">
  <TestFile>false</TestFile>
  <Header>
    <PIESVersion>6.1</PIESVersion>
    <BrandOwnerDUNS>000567647</BrandOwnerDUNS>
    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
    <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
    <TechnicalContact>Mark Toebben</TechnicalContact>
    <ContactEmail>mark@dcinet.com</ContactEmail>
  </Header>
  <Items>
    <Item MaintenanceType="C">
      <HazardousMaterialCode>N</HazardousMaterialCode>
      <ItemLevelGTIN GTINQualifier="UP">090127000380</ItemLevelGTIN>
      <PartNumber>0-1848-1</PartNumber>
      <BrandAAIAID>BBVL</BrandAAIAID>
      <BrandLabel>Holley</BrandLabel>
      <PartTerminologyID>5904</PartTerminologyID>
      <Descriptions>
        <Description MaintenanceType="C" DescriptionCode="DES" LanguageCode="EN">Street Carburetor</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="C" DescriptionCode="SHO" LanguageCode="EN">Crb</Description>
      </Descriptions>
      <Prices>
        <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="JBR">
          <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
          <Price UOM="PE">462.4600</Price>
        </Pricing>
        <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="RET">
          <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
          <Price UOM="PE">380.5500</Price>
        </Pricing>
        <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="WD1">
          <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
          <Price UOM="PE">314.4700</Price>
        </Pricing>
      </Prices>
      <ExtendedInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="CTO" LanguageCode="EN">US</ExtendedProductInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="NPC" LanguageCode="EN">A</ExtendedProductInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="HTS" LanguageCode="EN">8409914000</ExtendedProductInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="NAF" LanguageCode="EN">B</ExtendedProductInformation>
      </ExtendedInformation>
      <ProductAttributes>
        <ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="SKU" LanguageCode="EN">BBVL0-1848-1</ProductAttribute>
        <ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="ModDate" LanguageCode="EN">2012-12-31</ProductAttribute>
      </ProductAttributes>
      <Packages>
        <Package MaintenanceType="C">
          <PackageLevelGTIN>00090127000380</PackageLevelGTIN>
          <PackageUOM>EA</PackageUOM>
          <QuantityofEaches>1</QuantityofEaches>
          <Dimensions UOM="IN">
            <Height>7.5000</Height>
            <Width>11.0000</Width>
            <Length>12.2500</Length>
          </Dimensions>
          <Weights UOM="PG">
            <Weight>13.500</Weight>
            <DimensionalWeight>6.09</DimensionalWeight>
          </Weights>
        </Package>
      </Packages>
    </Item>
    <Item MaintenanceType="C">
      <HazardousMaterialCode>N</HazardousMaterialCode>
      <ItemLevelGTIN GTINQualifier="UP">090127539248</ItemLevelGTIN>
      <PartNumber>0-1850C</PartNumber>
      <BrandAAIAID>BBVL</BrandAAIAID>
      <BrandLabel>Holley</BrandLabel>
      <PartTerminologyID>5904</PartTerminologyID>
      <Descriptions>
        <Description MaintenanceType="C" DescriptionCode="DES" LanguageCode="EN">Street/Strip Carburetor</Description>
        <Description MaintenanceType="C" DescriptionCode="SHO" LanguageCode="EN">Crb</Description>
      </Descriptions>
      <Prices>
        <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="JBR">
          <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
          <Price UOM="PE">399.6600</Price>
        </Pricing>
        <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="RET">
          <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
          <Price UOM="PE">281.5500</Price>
        </Pricing>
        <Pricing MaintenanceType="C" PriceType="WD1">
          <PriceSheetNumber>L30779-13</PriceSheetNumber>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <EffectiveDate>2013-01-01</EffectiveDate>
          <Price UOM="PE">271.7700</Price>
        </Pricing>
      </Prices>
      <ExtendedInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="CTO" LanguageCode="EN">US</ExtendedProductInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="NPC" LanguageCode="EN">A</ExtendedProductInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="HTS" LanguageCode="EN">8409914000</ExtendedProductInformation>
        <ExtendedProductInformation MaintenanceType="C" EXPICode="NAF" LanguageCode="EN">B</ExtendedProductInformation>
      </ExtendedInformation>
      <ProductAttributes>
        <ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="SKU" LanguageCode="EN">BBVL0-1850C</ProductAttribute>
        <ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="ModDate" LanguageCode="EN">2012-12-31</ProductAttribute>
      </ProductAttributes>
      <Packages>
        <Package MaintenanceType="C">
          <PackageLevelGTIN>00090127539248</PackageLevelGTIN>
          <PackageUOM>EA</PackageUOM>
          <QuantityofEaches>1</QuantityofEaches>
          <Dimensions UOM="IN">
            <Height>7.5000</Height>
            <Width>11.0000</Width>
            <Length>12.2500</Length>
          </Dimensions>
          <Weights UOM="PG">
            <Weight>13.750</Weight>
            <DimensionalWeight>6.09</DimensionalWeight>
          </Weights>
        </Package>
      </Packages>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</PIES>
```

The other issue is within the CSV file, the data is not comma separated but rather on a new line as seen below. I'd like it to be separated by a comma but don't know how to fix this. May someone point me in the right direction?

```
N
090127000380
0-1848-1
BBVL
Holley
5904
"Street Carburetor"
Crb
L30779-13
USD
2013-01-01
462.4600
L30779-13
USD
2013-01-01
380.5500
L30779-13
USD
2013-01-01
314.4700
US
A
8409914000
B
BBVL0-1848-1
2012-12-31
00090127000380
EA
1
7.5000
11.0000
12.2500
13.500
6.09
```

Comment: Where is the data? Please specify to make your first question clearer.

Comment: Hey there! I posted the sample data -- do you see it? That data is within my XML file, 'text.xml'.

Comment: So you're only interested in the data you posted? I.e., basic data plus the first pricing info?

Comment: I apologize! I'm updating the data now. :)

Comment: The one problem is that you don't understand how http://php.net/fputcsv works. I suggest you create yourself a different test-application that is just creating a CSV file based on an example array to get used to it. The other part of the question I didn't review in detail, you probably want to query the data before you convert it. I suggest you look for related simplexml tagged questions, e.g. with xpath and iterators.

Comment: So somebody has written you some code and now you complain it doesn't work perfectly for you? Well, why have you accepted the answer then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102105/convert-xml-to-csv-with-php

Comment: Hey there, Hakre. - I accepted the answer because the question I asked was actually answered in that particular case. I'm still trying to figure it out obviously but that question was answered. I apologize if I used the site improperly.

Comment: Well if you generalize from your concrete problem, you're getting closer to a) writing a better question and b) learning something. Keep in mind we don't ask questions here for our own only, but also for future users. So we pick our concrete problem, turn it into a programming problem (which often already solves the concrete problem but if not we then) and put it onto this website and hope for an answer. If we know the answer, we answer it our own. It's more work, but most often very effective and future users have some use of it, too. So don't get stuck in the concrete problem :)