# Convert XML into Excel

Tags: xml

I am working actually with a company and they use to work with some data in XML format. My task since two weeks there is to find a way to convert a part of these XML data into an excel data (See Example below).

The XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>  
<instance>
<datarow>
 <element id="ID_USER">.anonymous</element> 
 <element id="knri2">147510257</element> 
 <element id="jahr">2016</element> 
 <element id="berichtigung">false</element> 
 <element id="anzeige">false</element> 
 <element id="widerruf">false</element> 
 <element id="Uname">Eli A.  GmbH & Co.</element> 
 <element id="Ustrasse">Mezutball. 23</element> 
 <element id="Uhausnr" /> 
 <element id="Uplz">97052</element> 
 <element id="Uort">Sokode</element> 
 <element id="knri1">TG</element> 
 <element id="Uart" /> 
 <element id="Utelefon" /> 
 <element id="Uemail" /> 
 <element id="Hname" /> 
 <element id="Hart" /> 
 <element id="Hstrasse" /> 
 <element id="Hhausnr" /> 
 <element id="Hplz" /> 
 <element id="Hort" /> 
 <element id="Htelefon" /> 
 <element id="Hemail" /> 
 <element id="quartal">Juni</element> 
 <element id="zlnr" /> 
 <element id="ffw_version">ZM_Formular_online V2.0</element> 
</datarow>
<dataset id="tbl_ZM_tabelle">
<datarow>
 <element id="knre1">AT</element> 
 <element id="knre2">U51877704</element> 
 <element id="umsatz_art">0</element> 
 <element id="betrag">99</element> 
</datarow>
 <datarow>
<element id="knre1">AT</element> 
<element id="knre2">U63661718</element> 
<element id="umsatz_art">0</element> 
<element id="betrag">196</element> 
</datarow>
<datarow>
 <element id="knre1">CZ</element> 
<element id="knre2">45794863</element> 
<element id="umsatz_art">0</element> 
<element id="betrag">-263</element> 
</datarow>
<datarow>
<element id="knre1">PL</element> 
<element id="knre2">6762147058</element> 
<element id="umsatz_art">0</element> 
<element id="betrag">158</element> 
</datarow>
</instance>
```

How I should transform it:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGTLr.png)

Comment: You could use a language such as PHP along with PHPExcel to do the conversion.

Comment: Another method would be [PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/). Then you could run it from your scheduling software or something like Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not much data you can use some online converters.

http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htmb
or
http://codebeautify.org/xml-to-csv-converter#

Also you can use PHP and here is similiar question here: [Convert XML to CSV with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102105/convert-xml-to-csv-with-php)